# Using environment variables in Python

Tags: python, variables, environment

I have an environment variable called %CCDeviceID%. When I run a command using python in Command Prompt, I want to be able to use this variable, and including %CCDeviceID% in the script doesn't work. How can I implement environment variables into my python script?

Thanks
Ed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`os.environ`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.environ):

```
import os
print os.environ['CCDeviceID']
```

Comment: Works perfect, I had the os.environ part, just hadn't imported OS... will mark as answer when it allows me

Answer (score 3):

You can get a listing of all environment variables available to you simply by doing the following:

```
>>> import os
>>> print os.environ
```

`os.environ` is a dictionary mapping env variable name to its value
In your case, you probably need to omit the `%` symbols. To get `CCDeviceID`.